# Spring boot with Keycloak to secure rest services

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have created two Roles in keycloak,
FARMER and 
FIELD_STAFF

And Created a User Rahul and mapped it with FARMER role.

I have created below client in keycloak.
[image]

I have a web service where I only want to access it by FARMER Role.
I have created a token and passing it while calling the rest services.But I am getting unauthorized access error in response.

Below I am adding Token generation screen and Keycloak configuration.

[image]

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
    package com.cropin.farmerservice.config;

import com.cropin.farmerservice.controller.FarmerController;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakClientRequestFactory;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakRestTemplate;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class,
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager"))
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws  Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate(){
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/farmer/*").hasRole("FARMER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 8085


keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=farmer_demo
keycloak.resource=farmer-service
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

Below is the response I am getting.

[image]

Comment: try to send by Authorization header

Answer (score 0):

You will need `RPT` token in order to get access to you APIs not just access token, use the generated `access_token` to generate rpt one, `PRT` token is the one that actually holds the permissions.

[keycloak authorization services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#authorization-services)

**This is how i generate RPT tokens when i work on backend development:**

- From terminal, you can get tokens from keycloak (to use with postman or other rest test tools):

  1. Get access token:

     ```
      curl -v -d 'client_secret={keycloak client secret}' -d 'username={user name}' -d 'password={password}' -d 'client_id={keycloak client id}' -d 'grant_type=password' 'http://{keycloak url or host:port}/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/token'
     ```
  2. Get rpt token which will be used during test

     ```
      curl -v -X POST \
      http://{keycloak url or host:port}/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid- 
      connect/token \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer { token string from previous command result }" \
      --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
      --data "audience={keycloak client id}"
     ```

Please see [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_obtaining_permissions) section for more details...